# Introducing The Reference Desk

Tags: feature-request

In my humble opinion, a lot of new visitors come to this stack reasonably expecting help finding historical sources, and often get their fingers burned. For this reason I have set up [a new chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53139/the-reference-desk) where their questions can be reposted. I hope all and sundry find it useful, and please send users there if they fall foul of our reference rules. Thanks!

Apparently someone just went and deleted, can't even see it in frozen rooms. A little rude if you ask me!

I still think we should send the reference requests to chat... we can use the main chat room.

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea.

One thing I'd suggest: Make sure to post something in it once a week. Perhaps a book recommendation? Not only does that give people a reason to go check it periodically, but it will keep the chat room from getting locked/deleted for inactivity.

Comment: Sure, I can do that. I encourage anyone and everyone who has such recommendations to post them... don't know if I'm knowledgable enough to post one a week! :)